# How can I merge 3 datasets in R without creating duplicates?

Tags: r, merge, data-preprocessing

|  | var1 |
| --- | --- |
| a | 4 |
| b | 2 |

|  | var2 |
| --- | --- |
| a | 5 |
| b | 9 |

|  | var3 |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| b | 3 |

I have 3 datasets like these, with same lenght rows, same subjects but different variables.

I want something like this:

|  | var1 | var2 | var3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 4 | 5 | 1 |
| b | 2 | 9 | 3 |

but using `merge` creates thousands of new rows with duplicates.

Comment: Maybe just column bind? `cbind(d1, d2, d3)`

Comment: I don't know why I decided to complicate the issue by using merge, anyway it worked of course, thanks